# How to avoid receiving requests sent before the backend launched?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, frontend, backend

I'm building a simple backend with express. I have a frontend that can send it some requests.
If I send it a request, it works fine. The problem is if I stop the backend from running and then launch it again, it operates again on the same request. If I stop it and launch it again, the old request is not there anymore and it works as expected until other requests.

Here is the code for the post request

```
app.post('/api/semi', (req, res)=>{
  if (val.validaSeme(req.body)) {
    console.log('Nuovo seme');
  } else {
    console.log('Seme non valido');
  }
});
```

I don' know, but it might also be a frontend problems that sends twice the same request. So here's the code I used for that as well (Angular)

```
addSeme(seme : Seme): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<Seme>(this.semiUrl, seme, this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError<Seme>('addSeme'))
    );
  }
```

The same thing happens for put and delete, I haven't tried with get. It also happens, when I launch the backend, for requests made while it wasn't running.

Thank you in advance.